# c# string padded now want it short

Tags: c#, string, padding

So I have two string that were padded, but now I want them show and Trim() doesn't seem to want to do it.

```
String devicename = "".PadRight(100);

String deviceversion = "".PadRight(100);

bool isDeviceReady = capGetDriverDescriptionA(i, ref devicename, 100, ref deviceversion, 100);
```

later I use the strings like in the below:

```
Messagebox.show("Device Name="+devicename.Trim()+" , Device Version="+deviceversion.Trim());
```

All that is shown is "`Device Name=name of the device`"

Thoughts?

Comment: @Brian. Let us know what you are expecting to see and what you _think_ Trim will do for you. Frankly, I don't see anything unexpected with what you are showing us.

Comment: @Jim The unexpected thing is that the message box does not show "Device Version=..." - only the first part of the string. The reason is IMHO that the `devicename` string contains `null` value and so MessageBox ignores the rest of the string.

Comment: @TomasPetricek, Yup, you are right about "Device Version" not being there. Have to say I missed that.  As far as the string _containing_ a null value, I can't speak to that, but it seems plausible. I was too hung up on the PadRight vs. Trim "issue"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was pretty simple. Tomas Petrick was on the right track. It, the string, returned was a null terminated (also called a zero-terminated) string.  Then I just needed to remove the null terminator from the strings.

```
devicename = devicename.trim('\0');
```

Comment: When using it in a loop I need to reset the string to the original "devicename = "".PadRight(100);"  The API doesn't like that it was Trimmed.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you padding the strings at all? It looks like you are just filling the strings with spaces that will get replaced later by content, but judging from your question I don't see why this is necessary. What is wrong with just:

```
String devicename = "";
String deviceversion = "";

bool isDeviceReady = capGetDriverDescriptionA(i, ref devicename, 100, ref deviceversion, 100);
```

Comment: Maybe the OP thinks that strings are mutable?

Comment: Technically this isn't an answer, it's a comment, but no downvote from me this time because it's too long for a comment AND because I agree with you.

Comment: You've made assumptions about the API call, I've come across many where you provide a buffer for the API to fill. This answer and comments are off topic.

Comment: I would've put this in a comment, but I was just short of reputation to be able to :P

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `StringBuilder` instead of `string` when calling an API function that returns a zero-terminated string. The behaviour you're getting probably follows from the fact that the API writes zero value at the end of the string (to terminate it), while .NET treats it as a normal string containing zero value.

Alternatively, look at [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da/clr/thread/425105d9-ff54-404d-8039-305fff4f6b06), which suggests to annotate the parameter with `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWSTR)]` attribute. Then the PInovke mechanism should take care of zero value at the end automatically.

Comment: I guess that makes sense.  StringBuilder doesn't seem to work though.